# Read attributes of element and replace part of string in the attribute based on some criteria

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a problem in creating the xsl transformation for below case:

```
<text>
<data>
<Object class="CENTRE" Name="Country-1/CENTRE-1/RTY-1" version="1">
    <p name="Map">20</p>
    <p name="Required">0</p>
</Object>
<Object class="LEFT" Name="Country-1/LEFT-1/RTY-1" version="1">
    <p name="Map">20</p>
    <p name="Required">0</p>
</Object>
<Object class="RIGHT" Name="Country-1/RIGHT-1/UIO-1" version="1">
    <p name="Map">20</p>
    <p name="Required">0</p>
</Object>
</data>
</text>
```

In above snippet i have to:

1. Find element for which class attribute is **CENTRE**
2. And Replace **CENTRE** with **SIDE** in class attribute value and sub string replace for **Name** attribute value from Country-1/**CENTRE**-1/RTY-1 to Country-1/**SIDE**-1/RTY-1**.
3. Rest elements should not be affected and should be retained as it is.

I tried substring replacement through a method from replace-all-string but was unsuccessful.
Thanks in advance

OutPut xml sholud be like:

```
<text>
<data>
<Object class="SIDE" Name="Country-1/SIDE-1/RTY-1" version="1">
<p name="Map">20</p>
<p name="Required">0</p>
</Object>
<Object class="LEFT" Name="Country-1/LEFT-1/RTY-1" version="1">
<p name="Map">20</p>
<p name="Required">0</p>
</Object>
<Object class="RIGHT" Name="Country-1/RIGHT-1/UIO-1" version="1">
<p name="Map">20</p>
<p name="Required">0</p>
</Object>
</data>
</text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Object[@class = 'CENTRE' ]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:value-of select="'SIDE'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before( @Name,'CENTRE' ), 'SIDE', substring-after( @Name, 'CENTRE'))"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate following output:

```
<text>
    <data>
        <Object class="SIDE" Name="Country-1/SIDE-1/RTY-1" version="1">
            <p name="Map">20</p>
            <p name="Required">0</p>
        </Object>
        <Object class="LEFT" Name="Country-1/LEFT-1/RTY-1" version="1">
            <p name="Map">20</p>
            <p name="Required">0</p>
        </Object>
        <Object class="RIGHT" Name="Country-1/RIGHT-1/UIO-1" version="1">
            <p name="Map">20</p>
            <p name="Required">0</p>
        </Object>
    </data>
</text>
```

Comment: Thanks hr_117 ... That helped a lot:)